# Show only active records and remove expired records using linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

RecordExpiration is a datetime field. I have to show only active records which are not expired.

```
var triggerEvents = ctx.CDB.Admin_FlexTriggerEvents.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.RecordID == RecordID)
                         .Select(x => new TriggerEvent
                         {
                             RecordID = x.RecordID,
                             FlexTriggerType_RecordID = x.FlexTriggerType_RecordID,
                             Condition = x.FlexTriggerType.Condition,
                             MergeData = x.FlexTriggerType.FlexTriggerEntityType.MergeData,
                             FlexTriggerEventNotifications = x.FlexTriggerEventNotifications,
                             FlexTriggerEventEmployeeMessages = x.FlexTriggerEventEmployeeMessages,
                             FlexTriggerEventNudgeEmails = x.FlexTriggerEventNudgeEmails,
                             FlexTriggerEventDataExchanges = x.FlexTriggerEventDataExchanges,
                             FlexTriggerEventCreateGroupComms = x.FlexTriggerEventCreateGroupComms,
                             Name = x.Name,
                             RecordExpiration = x.RecordExpiration
                           
                         }).ToList();
```

Not sure where can I add a condition. All of the records before today can come in expired records.

Comment: add to WHERE condition: `x.RecordExpiration <= DateTime.Now`. BTW you are currently using condition `x => x.RecordID == RecordID` and this will always return just the one record (=RecordID), not a list of records

Comment: @TheMixy - I guess RecordID it NOT the id of the event records but the id of some relation.

Comment: It might help to read some basics about how to work with linq https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/

Comment: @ChristophLütjen: might be... It's something Shenal should elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to show only active records which are not expired.

You forgot to tell us what an active record is. And how do you know that a record is not expired. Is that in property `RecordExpiration`?

```
int recordId = ...
var activeNonExpiredRecords = ctx.CDB.Admin_FlexTriggerEvents
    .Where(flexTriggerEvent => flexTriggerEvent.RecordID == recordID
        && !flexTriggerEvent.RecordExpiration
        && flexTriggerEvent.IsActive)
    .Select(record => ...)
```

In words: from all FlexTriggerEvents, keep only those FlexTriggerEvents that have a value for property RecordId that equals the value of recordId, AND that have a false value for property `RecordExpiration` AND that have a true value for `IsActive`. From the remaining records, select ...

If you don't have a property IsActive, create a Boolean expression that represents IsActive:

For instance: active if less than a week old:

```
&& DateTime.Today - flexTriggerEvent.EventDate < TimeSpan.FromDays(7)
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what an active record is. And how do you know that a record is not expired. Is that in property RecordExpiration? >>> records before today are expired records. Record Expiration do not have any property.